# Url rewrite is not working in some cases with XAMPP in Windows 7

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP website hosted at localhost on my Windows 7 PC, running XAMPP 1.8.2.

And I have rewrite rules as below:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

To rewrite the URL so it will always go into something like: http://**mysite.com/index.php?rt=[controller]/[action]/[params]**

It works prefect until I found it failed when processing url like: http://**mysite.com/error/xxx**. It returns a 404 status other than goes to http://**mysite.com/index.php?rt=error/xxx**. (I do NOT have an sub directory call error/ under my website root folder)

I carefully checked my PHP code and I am sure it is not the cause, and I upload my website to a remote server and everything is fine. So I am pretty sure something is not properly configured in my XAMPP (Apache), that makes the /error/xxx request was treated differently.

Also I found visiting http://**mysite.com/error/** gives me 403 but http://**mysite.com/[something_else]/** is fine.

Just in case, I paste my vhost.conf here as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\htdocs\mysite.dev"
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And related httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "E:\htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well have you tried creating intentional error urls via: `ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.html`?

Comment: yes, I did that in .htaccess, no help.

Comment: Try #commenting out one line at a time and seeing how that effects the request to the "403 error" page.

Comment: It seems the request never reaches the stage of processing the .htaccess file. I found this in the apache server log: `Cannot serve directory C:/xampp/apache/error/: No matching DirectoryIndex found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`. I am now even more confused, it makes no sense for the request goes into the xampp/apache directory. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure it out after wasting another hour on it!

There is configuration file called `httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf` under `/xampp/apache/conf/extra`, and inside it's something like this:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
<IfModule include_module>
<IfModule negotiation_module>
Alias /error/ "C:/xampp/apache/error/"

<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/error">
    AllowOverride None
    Options IncludesNoExec
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Require all granted
    LanguagePriority en cs de es fr it ja ko nl pl pt-br ro sv tr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The line `Alias /error/ "C:/xampp/apache/error/"` handles all the request matches `domainname.com/error/` and rewrite it to `C:/xampp/apache/error/`.

Simply commenting out the line solves my problem. Not sure what it does but make things done.

Comment: I met same problem but finally solved it after reading your answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment it sounds like Apache isn't even correctly configured to the path with your site!

You need to edit the `Xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file.

First make a BACKUP copy of it.

Edit the line that starts with...

`DocumentRoot "`

..if it is a Windows machine and it uses / instead of \ retain those.

Then you need to edit the line that starts with...

`<Directory "`

Be aware that there is also a CGI version of this.

If you have correctly edited the file save and then restart Apache. Changes will NOT take effect until you restart Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figure it out myself :-).